# Oracle SQL: INSERT with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-select

i have a query like this:

`insert into book ('book_id', 'category_id', 'book_name', 'buy_price', 'sell_price') values ('B-001, 'BOM-001', 'Tarzan', 200, 300);`

is it possible to get the ***category_id*** from another table which is ***category*** table using **select** and condition **where category_name = 'adventure'** so i get the **BOM-001**? can anyone give me a sample of that query ?

thank you

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results.

Comment: keeping aside **category_id** column, how do you perform insert operation? Do you have an attempt even it seems not logical, or not syntatically correct ..?

Comment: Single quotes (`'`) are string delimiters. If you need name delimiters (you don't, as your names neither contain special characters, nor do they equal keywords), use double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would look like:

```
insert into book (book_id, category_id, book_name, buy_price, sell_price)
    select ?, c.category_id, ?, ?, ?
    from category c
    where c.category_name = ?;
```

The `?` are placeholders for your constant values.  Note that there are no single quotes around the column names for the `insert`.

Comment: its worked like a charm, thank you very much.
i wonder is there a way(query)/short way if im gonna inserting multiple rows/records ?

Comment: @yazidnasution . .  You may want to ask another question.  Explain where the multiple rows are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

First: a single value can always be replaced by a query that returns a single value:

```
insert into book (book_id, category_id, book_name, buy_price, sell_price)
values ('B-001', 
        (select category_id from category where category_name = 'adventure'),
        'Tarzan',
        200,
        300
       );
```

Second: You can insert rows you select from somewhere:

```
insert into book (book_id, category_id, book_name, buy_price, sell_price)
select 'B-001', category_id, 'Tarzan', 200, 300
from category where category_name = 'adventure';
```

Comment: i've tried the second option you gave me and it worked like a charm, thank you very much.
i wonder is there a way(query)/short way if im gonna inserting multiple rows/records ?

Comment: The second statement is capable of inserting multiple rows at once, e.g. by recplacing `category_name = 'adventure'` with `category_name in ('adventure', 'fun')`.